# AWS CloudFormation template to attach new EBS volume to Windows and partition

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, windows-server-2008-r2

I want to create a CloudFormation template that will create an EBS Volume and attach it to an existing Amazon EC2 instance. It should then partition the disk (single partition) and assign a specific Drive letter.

Currently I am stuck with connecting the Windows machine to perform DISKPART operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can certainly configure the CloudFormation template to provision an EBS volume for a Windows instance.

However, anything after that requires interaction with the Windows operating system and cannot be specified as a native CloudFormation instruction. Instead, you would need to [pass (or trigger) a script](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ec2-windows-user-data.html) that would perform the command-line operations.